# How do I track transactions on my wallet?

Tags: wallet, solana.py, dapp

I am currently working on a Shop based which accepts Solana as the form of currency, I want to know which wallets are transferring funds to my wallet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method [getSignaturesForAddress](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getSignaturesForAddress) to get a list of signatures, this method can receive your address. After that you pass the signatures to the method [getParsedTransactions](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getParsedTransactions) which returns information about the transactions.

Keep in mind you will only have token mints and not symbols like USDC, but beside that you can get everything you need, from, time, mint, amount, among others useful to identify the transaction.

Comment: Note that you can use the batch RPC request format to run multiple requests at once for efficiency. https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification#batch

Comment: many rpc service providers restrict or reject batched method calls to curb abuse